# Using FluentValidation to create validation rule for more than one property

Tags: fluentvalidation

I am trying to implement a complex validation scenario in FluentValidation.

Let's say I have a Car class.  It has four properties: Color, Make, Model, Year.

I want to construct a validation rule that involves three of these properties.   For the sake of conversation, let's say I want a validation rule like the following:

```
if car.make = nissan and car.year = 2010 then
    if car.color <> green then
       throw a validation error since the system does not support 2010 nissans that are not green.
    end     
end
```

I know this is a silly example.  I, however, have validation rules in my app that involve more than one aspect of my object.   This is the heart of my question.

I have tried to follow the guidance from http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom on using "Using AbstractValidator.Custom" .

Does anyone have other working examples of the AbstractValidator.Custom working?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simple way of implementing validations involving multiple properties

```
public class CarValidator : AbstractValidator<Car>
{
    public CarValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.Color).NotEqual("Green").When(MakeIsNisssanAndYearIs2000))
    }

    private bool MakeIsNisssanAndYearIs2000(Car arg)
    {
        return arg.Make == "Nissan" && arg.Year == 2000;
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

You can parameterise `MakeIsNissanAndYearIs2000` method so that make and model are passed to the method as parameters. But this should give you an idea of how to implement validations involving multiple properties